# How to inject an id attribute to HTML with its value coming from a for loop using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
const renderProgress = () => {
  let qIndex = 0;
  const lastQuestion = 20
  const queryAllProgress = document.getElementsByClassName("query__all-progress");
  const queryAllProgressId = document.createAttribute("id");
  for (qIndex; qIndex <= lastQuestion; qIndex++) {
    queryAllProgressId.value += qIndex;
    queryAllProgress.setAttributeNode(queryAllProgressId);
 }
};
```

```css
.query__all-progress {
      width: 0.9rem;
      height: 0.9rem;
      margin: 0 0.03rem;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 40%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="query__all-progress"></div>
```

As you can see, I am trying to get the div element by the class name `query__all-progress` 'cause I need to give it an attribute of `id=""`. And, the value of the id should be from the for loop, which is the **qIndex**. I tried to do this but it doesn't work. Please help.

I'm just trying to refactor this code guys. Please help:

```
const renderProgress = () => {
  const lastQuestion = 20;
  let qIndex = 0;
  const queryProgress = document.getElementById("query__progress");
  for (qIndex; qIndex <= lastQuestion; qIndex++) {
    queryProgress.innerHTML += `<div class='query__all-progress' id="${qIndex}"></div>`;
  }
};
```

Comment: what is qIndex ?

Comment: qindex should have a value, inside the for loop, you should say something like qindex=0

Comment: Oops! I'm terribly sorry about that guys. I've declared this variable at the very top of my long code so I forgot sorry. `let qIndex = 0;`

Comment: I don't know what you're building, but giving  a 20 ids to an element is bad implementation for 2 reasons, first, you're referring to the same element, so why giving the same element 20 ids? Second: handling all these ids later will be hard.

Comment: I should say something important: the id name cannot start with a number

Comment: @Mathew, please, take a look at my original code I've added above. I'm just trying to refactor that code. So please bear with me I'm begging you. I'm a beginner in JavaScript.

Comment: You have to give the id="${qIndex}" another name, now the id will be numeric for each div, so  just cahnge id="${qIndex}" to id="a_${qIndex}" and it should work properly.

Comment: Id name can't begin with numeric value. Id="0" is wrong. Id="a_0" is correct.

Comment: Actually your refactored code is a very good implementation, just fix the mistake I've mentioned above.

Comment: I'm sorry @Mathew, but I want to make it clear that this code of mine works just fine. Everything here works just fine, including the id. I'm just having a problem with refactoring the code and all I'm looking for is a better approach, if there is one.

Comment: Your refactored code is a very good implementation, if you're looking for a better way, I can say that this depends on what you're trying to do, if you're going to style these 20 divs after they've been added, it's better not to give each one of them a specific id except if each one of these 20 divs will have a different style. But if all of these divs will have the same style later once they've been added to the body (after the loop breaks), it's better to use a united class name instead of a different id name for each div, and for the class: you define it inside your css file with its styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to solve it like this:

In your **.html** file create a  element to serve as a container

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

I modified your function a bit like this:

```js
const renderProgress = () => {

        // COUNTING VARIABLES
        let qIndex = 0;
        const lastQuestion = 20

        // TO STORE EACH ELEMENT
        let querys = '';

        // PROCESS
        for (qIndex; qIndex <= lastQuestion; qIndex++) {
            querys += '<div class="query__all-progress" id="'+ qIndex +'"></div>';
        }
        // INJECTING GENERATED ELEMENTS TO CONTAINER
        document.getElementById('container').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', querys);
 }

 renderProgress();
```

.css stays the same

```css
.query__all-progress {
      width: 0.9rem;
      height: 0.9rem;
      margin: 0 0.03rem;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 40%;
    }
```

You should have something like this:

[image]

And in the inspector:

[image]

I hope it helps you.